# Как удалить localStorage через определенное время

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Есть функция которая показывает баннер, нужно сделать так что бы при клике по кнопке банер перестал показываться ровно один час. Делал путем записи в localStorage. Но почему то условия с временем не работают, вот сам код:

```
               function vspl(){
                      $('.vspl').css('display', 'flex');
                      $('.vspl-img2').css('display', 'flex');
                      $('.vspl-img2').animate({'left':'26%'},800);
                    }
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var ls2 = localStorage.getItem('ban');
                        var limit = 1 * 3600 * 1000;
                        if(localStorage.ban){
                        setTimeout(vspl, 333000);
                        }
                        else{
                        setTimeout(vspl, 3000);
                        }
                        $('.vspl-reset').click(function(){
                          $('.vspl').css('display', 'none');
                          var ls = localStorage.setItem('ban', +new Date());
                          var ls2 = localStorage.getItem('ban');
                          var ps = parseInt(ls2, 10);
                          if (ps === null) {
                            localStorage.setItem('ban', +new Date());
                          } 
                          else if(+new Date() - ps > limit){
                            localStorage.clear();
                            localStorage.setItem('ban', +new Date());
                            console.log("ready");
                        }
                        });
                        $('.vspl').click(function(){
                          $('.vspl').css('display', 'none');
                          var ls = localStorage.setItem('ban', +new Date());
                          var ls2 = localStorage.getItem('ban');
                          var ps = parseInt(ls2, 10);
                          if (ps === null) {
                            localStorage.setItem('ban', +new Date());
                          } 
                          else if(+new Date() - ps > limit){
                            localStorage.clear();
                            localStorage.setItem('ban', +new Date());
                            console.log("ready");
                        }
                    })
                    });
```

То-есть условие else if(+new Date() - ls > limit) - не срабатывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(() => {

  const $banner = $('.vspl');

  const blockTime = localStorage.getItem('blockTime');
  if (blockTime !== null) {

    // Сверяем время блокировки с текущим временем
    if (+new Date() >= parseInt(blockTime)) {

      // Если время блокировки вышло, то очищаем localStorage
      localStorage.removeItem('blockTime');

    } else {

      // Иначе скрываем элемент
      $banner.hide();

    }

  }

  $banner.click(() => {

    // Скрываем элемент
    $banner.hide();

    // Устанавливаем время блокировки (текущее время + 1 час)
    localStorage.setItem('blockTime', +new Date() + (3600 * 1000));

  }); 

});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Что может означать этот код?

```
    var ls = localStorage.setItem('ban', +new Date());
    if (ls === null) {
```

... и чему здесь равно `ls`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: Запись в localStorage времени клика и проверка была ли запись, все же ясно...

Comment: @ilyaaa521 "проверка была ли запись" - прочитайте по ссылке, что возвращает `setItem`.

Comment: Ошибся, не записал значение в getItem, у меня в начале кода есть переменная ls(getItem), ее надо переименовать и проверку по ней сделать? И уже отнимать от текущей даты?

Comment: Поправил код, сейчас посмотрите